# Why $W_{t}^3$ is not a martigale?(by Definition)

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic

If $W_t$ be a wiener process then,how can i show that $W_{t}^{3}$ is not a martingale by definition?

Comment: what about showing that $E[W^3_t | \sigma(W_s)]$ is not $W^3_s$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that, for $0 \leq s < t$,
\begin{align*}
W_t^3 &= (W_t-W_s+W_s)^3\\
&= (W_t-W_s)^3 + 3(W_t-W_s)^2 W_s + 3 (W_t-W_s) W_s^2 + W_s^3.
\end{align*}
Moreover,
\begin{align*}
E\big( (W_t-W_s)^3 \mid \mathcal{F}_s\big) &= E\big( (W_t-W_s)^3\big)\\
&= 0,\\
E\big((W_t-W_s)^2 W_s \mid \mathcal{F}_s\big) &= W_s E\big( (W_t-W_s)^2\big)\\
&= (t-s)W_s,
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
E\big( (W_t-W_s) W_s^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_s\big) &= W_s^2 E\big( (W_t-W_s)\big)\\
&=0.
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
E\big(W_t^3\mid \mathcal{F}_s\big) &= 3(t-s)W_s+W_s^3.
\end{align*}
That is, $\{W_t^3 \mid t\geq 0\}$ is not a martingale. We note that, however, 
$\{W_t^3 -3tW_t \mid t\geq 0\}$ is a martingale. See Question
[Show that $E[B_t|\mathscr{F}_s] = B_s$](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/14956/show-that-eb-t-mathscrf-s-b-s/14989#14989)